# How to simplify java code by moving from inheritance to composition

Tags: java, inheritance, enums, composition

I wrote the bottom level classes of multilevel inherited class but confused how to combine them to a single program. Someone suggested me to use composition instead of inheritance, and someone suggested to use `enum` to create anonymous subclass instead of complex inheritance structure. How can we use composition in place of inheritance or use `enum` instead of the inheritance that I used? What Should I do to simplify problem and How should it be done?

I am using Java to write a code to calculate tax. I am having base class `TaxPayer`. Taxpayer can have multiple `incomeSource`. There can be many types of `TaxPayer` or `IncomeSource`. There can be many income headings for each income source which is used to calculate `taxableIncome`. `taxRate` will be different for different type of `taxPayer` and `taxableIncome`. Final result will be `taxRate` applied to `taxableIncome`.

Base class Taxpayer is defined as

```
public abstract class TaxPayer {
    private List<IncomeSource> incomeSource;
    double taxRate;
    Address address;
    other attributes here;

    public Double getTaxRate(){
        return 0.25; //default tax rate
     }
}

public abstract class IncomeSource {
    private String incomeSourceName;
    private Double incomeHeading1, incomeHeading2, incomeHeading3, ...;
    private Double taxableIncome = incomeHeading1 + incomeHeading2 - incomeHeading3;
}
```

There can be some subclass of `IncomeSource` with different income headings. Similarly tax payer type can be modeled into following inheritance structure

```
Base Class: Taxpayer
    * IndividualPerson
        * Male, Female, OldAge
    * Business
        * Bank, ITIndustry, HydroElectricIndustry
    * TaxFree
        * SocialOrganization, ReligiousOrganization, PoliticalParty etc.
```

The subclasses of `TaxPayer` generally modifies the `taxRate` to be applied to `taxableIncome` and sometimes changes `taxableIncome` with some logic. For an example:

```
abstract class IndividualPerson extends TaxPayer{
    if (incomeSource.taxableIncome > 250000) taxRate = ratex;
    if (incomeSource.taxableIncome > 500000) taxRate = ratey;
    @override
    public getTaxRate() {
        return taxRate;
    }
}
class Female extends IndividualPerson {
    if (incomeSource.getNumberOfIncomeSource() > 1) taxRate = taxRate + rate1;
    else taxRate = taxRate - rate2
    if (address.isRural() = true) taxRate = taxRate - rate3;
    if (attributeX = true) taxRate = taxRate + rate4;
    if ("Some other attribute" = true) taxableIncome = taxableIncome - someAmount;
}
```

We have to check attributes of `Taxpayer` and `IncomeSource` to determine the `taxRate`. Sometimes, `taxableIncome` can be modified according to `taxPayer` type and other conditions.

I am confused how to combine bottom level classes together to make a useable code. Someone suggested me not to use complex multilevel inheritance, instead, use composition or `enum` to achieve the desired result with less complexity. How to do this? Please give answers with enough details for beginners to understand.

Comment: "I am confused how to combine bottom level classes together to make a useable code". I would suggest that you make your best effort given the classes you've got then post the result to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for people to comment. There are lots of different ways of doing it and none of them are necessarily wrong so the code review site may be a better fit for your question.

Comment: If you consider doing more with your application, consider using `BigDecimal`. Cumbersome to use, but `double` is just an approximation of real numbers; 0.20 cannot be represented exacty for instance. _After your first rewrite._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, i wont program your case out, but i will give you some guidlines to what composition is, and how to solve it with enums.
Your problem seems to be, that you have a TaxPayer, and the only thing that is shared, is the default tax rate.

With composition, instead of using inheritance, you have a instance of TaxPayer in your class:

```
public class TaxPayer {
    private List<IncomeSource> incomeSource;
    double taxRate;
    Address address;
    other attributes here;

    public Double getTaxRate(){
        return 0.25; //default tax rate
     }
}

public class Male {
   private TaxPayer taxPayer = new TaxPayer();

   public Double getTaxRate(){
      return taxPayer.getTaxRate();
   }
}
```

So instead of abstraction, you link the methods through that you want to use of TaxPayer.

With enums the solution would probally look something like this:

```
public enum TaxPayer {
  MALE,
  FEMALE {
    public Double getTaxRate(){
        return 1; //custom tax rate
    }
  };

  public Double getTaxRate(){
      return 0.25; //default tax rate
  }

}
```

Now you can use:

```
TaxPayer.MALE.getTaxRate();
```

in your code!

A third option would be defining an interface and define the defaultTaxRate as a constant.

```
public interface TaxPayer {
  Double getTaxRate();
}

public class Male implements TaxPayer {
  public Double getTaxRate(){
    return Constants.DEFAULT_TAX_RATE;
  }
}

public class Constants {
  public static final double DEFAULT_TAX_RATE = 0.25;
}
```

And now for the important bit, why would you any of these over extention.

First off, you can only extend 1 class, so it makes your class less versitile, and harder to use. The enum and interface solve this for you (since you can still apply the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to it).

```
public void foo(TaxPayer anyImplementationOfTaxPayer){
   bar(anyImplementationOfTaxPayer.getTaxRate());
}
```

As you see, by using an interface or an enum, its far more extendible than an abstract class.

Secondly, if you add a method to the abstract class, ALL the classes that extend from it will inherit this method, and are forced to deal with/implement behaviour of this extra method, or have a partly unusable API.

Answer (score 2):

It is better change to composition. 
You can do like this to change from multiple inheritance or interface to composition

1. Inheritance:

   ```
   Class A{ }
   Class B extends Class A{ }
   Class C extends Class B{ }
   ```
2. Interface:

   ```
   Interface A{ }
   Interface B implements Class A{ }
   Class C implements Class B{ }
   ```
3. Composition:

   ```
   class C{  
       A objA = new A();  
       B objB = new B();

       public void test(){  
           objA.doSomething();
       } 
       public void methodA(){ 
           objA.method();
       }
   }
   ```